# Google Analytics API errors on custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does google support selecting and filtering of custom dimensions in its API?  It errors out every time I try to make a query with ga:dimension1

Client code:

```
    //analytics.js include on the previous line        
    ga('create', 'UA-50XXXXXX-1', 'domain.com');
    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'var1' );
    ga('set', 'dimension2', 'var2' );
    ga('set', 'dimension3', 'var3' );
    ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I go to https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ and put in my account info,  ga:pageviews as the metrics and ga:dimension1 as the dimensions and it gives me this as a Query URI:

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3AXXXXXXXX&dimensions=ga%3Adimension1&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&start-date=2015-02-20&end-date=2015-02-26&max-results=50
```

When I run the Query URI it returns:

```
    Ack! There was an error!
    400 : Unknown dimension(s): ga:dimension1
```

Do I need to enable something on my account?  Do I need to go back to ga.js and custom vars

Comment: what do you mean by it gives you a query uri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you haven't enabled custom dimensions on your property in Google Analytics.

This article should explain how if you're unsure:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829

Comment: You're welcome. And since you're new to Stack Overflow, if this answer helped solve your problem, you should mark it as accepted and/or upvote it so others with the same problem will know this works.